# Girsanov theorem to show that a process is a solution of a certain SDE using measures on $C[0,1]$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Here is a statment in my book:

"Let $W_{\mathrm{x}}$ denote Wiener measure starting at $\mathrm{x}$ on $\Omega=\mathrm{C}\left([0, \mathrm{T}], \mathbb{R}^{\mathrm{n}}\right), \mathrm{T}<\infty,$ and let $W=\int W_{\mathrm{x}} \mathrm{d} \mathrm{x}$
be the stationary Wiener measure.

We denote by $\mathbb{D}$ the set of all probability measures on $\Omega$ which are equivalent to the stationary Wiener measure. Let $F_{\mathrm{t}}$ be the $\sigma$ -algebras of events observable up to time $t$. By Girsanov's theorem, any $P \in \mathbb{D}$ has a forward drift $\beta_{t}^{P},$ in the sense that, under $P,$ the coordinate process admits the
representations
$$
\begin{array}{ll}
\mathrm{dX}_{\mathrm{t}}=\beta_{\mathrm{t}}^{\mathrm{P}} \mathrm{d} \mathrm{t}+\mathrm{d} \mathrm{W}_{\mathrm{t}}, & \beta_{\mathrm{t}}^{\mathrm{P}} \text { is } F_{\mathrm{t}} \text { -measurable, }
\end{array}
$$

where $W_t$ is the standard Wiener processes adapted to $F_t$ ."

How can we use Girsanov to show this ? This is basically saying that if a process $X_t$ induces a measure on $C[0,T]$ that is equivalent to the Wiener measure, then it must satisfy the above SDE.

Comment: What book are you talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find Girsanov's theorem in the form we need in this [paper](http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~mdavis/course_material/MOP/CHANGES_OF_MEASURE.PDF) or in this [one](https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/gordanz/notes/girsanov.pdf).

It is confusing if you never saw "part b)" of the theorem in the first paper which is not on Wikipedia I believe. But so what you're saying is verbatim what the theorem says.